# Why do some of my tabs cause my content to shift slightly to the right?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a very rough mockup for a registration site I'm building that uses bootstrap tabs. However, when I select a few of my tabs, I notice all of the content gets shifted to the right by a few pixels.

See [here](http://tny.cz/cf102515) for my code, as it's too long to paste here. I don't think my JavaScript files would affect the appearance of the page when switching tabs, but if so, I'll attach them here if needed.

Notice how the page's content gets shifted to the right by a few pixels when switching from one of the following tabs: `Personal Info`, `State/Federal`, `Ethnicity`, `Birthplace/Language`, `Medical`, or `School Release` tab to either the `Contact/Siblings`, `Placement`, or `Emergency Contact` tab.

Comment: which browser do you use?

Comment: some browsers hide the scrollbar until content exceeds the browser window. Check to see if some of your tabs are activating the scrollbar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe it's because of the content height, on some tabs the vertical scrollbar shows up and pushes the content causing the shift. You can make the scrollbar show all the time by adding `overflow-y: scroll;` to the `body` element.

```
body {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```